# Storing custom class iOS 8 core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsobject

I am using an API and their classes don't seem to conform to Core Data.

The classes I am trying to store `AftershipCheckpoint` and `AftershipTracking`

The .h file for `AftershipTracking` looks like this

```
@interface AftershipTracking : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* createTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* updateTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* identifier;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* trackingNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* trackingPostalCode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* trackingShipDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* trackingAccountNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* slug;
@property (nonatomic) bool isActive;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary* customFields;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* customName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* deliveryTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* destionationCountryCode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* emails;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* expectedDeliveryDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* orderId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* orderIdPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* originCountryCode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* uniqueToken;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* shipmentPackageCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* shipmentType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* shipmentWeight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* shipmentWeightUnit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* signedBy;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* smses;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* source;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* tag;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* trackedCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* checkpoints;


- (NSString *)description;
```

It contains an array of `AftershipCheckpoint` so I figure I will need to configure this class as well.

```
@interface AftershipCheckpoint : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* createTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* slug;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* checkpointTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* city;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* state;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* countryCode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* countryName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* message;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* tag;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* zip;

- (NSString *)description;
```

My application has an array of `AftershipTracking` how would I go about storing the array for persistent data using Core Data or is there a better option?

Comment: How many objects of each class are you likely to have?

Comment: @pbasdf I would say no more than 10 checkpoints per Tracking, and no more than 100 tracking objects.

Comment: In which case, I think CoreData is indeed the way to go.  Checkpoints will be relatively easy to model, since CoreData supports NSDate and NSString attributes without problem.  The Trackings will be harder to model, since CoreData does not support array or dictionary attributes.  Typically collections are modelled as relationships to other entities, and to model those properly, you would need to know what datatypes they contain, which may be hidden by the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove one of the tracking from you model it will look something like this..

```
- (void)remove:(AftershipTracking *)package
{
    [_packages removeObject:package];
    [_delivered removeObject:package];
    [_inProgress removeObject:package];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tracking" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];
    NSPredicate *pred =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(trackingNumber = %@)", package.trackingNumber];
    [request setPredicate:pred];

    NSManagedObject *match = nil;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    match = objects.firstObject;
    [context deleteObject:match];

    [self sort];
    [context save:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in there seems to be ready to use NSCoding for persistence. To start, depending on the size you could save these arrays to NSUserDefaults, Or you could start up a Core Data Store and try persisting with a plist with it. In general first to make sure your logic is correct by using a human readable formate (plist in the case of iOS), then once you've got that in place switch the store to use SQLite, but you only really need to do this if you have many thousands of objects to persist.

Using NSUserDefaults, that Array will save inside the list of `AftershipTracking` as long as `AftershipCheckpoint` conforms to NSCoding.

Answer (score 1):

In AftershipTracking,

- Change `isActive` to an `NSNumber`. As an `NSNumber`, it can be saved in CoreData.
- I am guessing that `checkpoints` is an array of AftershipCheckpoint objects. This can be setup as a to many relationship in your model, which will change the type to `NSSet`. When you retrieve the `NSSet` out of CoreData, you can then convert it to an array with `[checkpoints allObjects]`.
- The other `NSArray`s and `NSDictionary`s need to be a [Transformable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html) object.

In AftershipCheckpoint,

- This class is fine, since it is a bunch of `NSString`s and an `NSDate`.

Both classes need to be a subclass of `NSManagedObjectModel`. It is probably a good idea to create them through the normal core data modeling options (be sure to import the core data framework). Check out [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) on core data.

Comment: A `BOOL` can be saved in Core Data without issue. A `bool` is slightly different. I assume by the poster's declaration that the `bool` is a mistake and `BOOL` is the correct type.